# Menu hover effect

Tags: dynamic, menu, hover, effect

I would like to create a hover effect like the left category menu on this demo page http://themeforest.net/item/mazine-wordpress-theme-a-wp-ecommerce-theme/full_screen_preview/198602

I tried to add padding-left:7px; in the css file, but this does not look the same.

Comment: show your code? and maybe we can help fix your problems?

Comment: Looks like they use a jQuery animation effect that sets the `padding-left` of the `LI` tag.  Though like @JohnRiselvato said, we'd have to see your code to see what you're doing differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you're asking exactly but if it's about how the list items slide over a little when you move your mouse over them, check out [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TGNr7/). It uses CSS3 transitions.

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

​

```
#menu li {
    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;    
    transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
#menu li:hover {
    padding-left:7px;
}
```

​

More info & demos:

- http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/css-fundametals-css-3-transitions/